# Get value of a checked radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get a value of a checked radio button of a group of related radio buttons without using their ids?  I can try something like this, but it is not generic enough.

```
var boxes = $('input[name=BankAccountTypeGroup]:checked');
$(boxes).each(function () {
   if ($(this).val() == 'Savings') {
       //
   }
})
```

Comment: What do you mean 'generic enough'? Please, explain yourself better.

Comment: There should only be one value for the checked radio button.  So something like:  $(this).val().  What I have works for checkboxes.

Comment: Shouldn't $('input[name=BankAccountTypeGroup]:checked').val() get the correct value for the checked radio for that group?? http://jsfiddle.net/xmz2K/ maybe show some html

Comment: Why is it not generic enough?  You could use var $radioValues = $('input[type="radio"]:checked'); to get all of the checked radio buttons, but I'm not understanding the issue.

Comment: If you are looking for an element with a specific value you can use `$('input[type="radio"][value="Savings"]')`

Comment: $(this).val() returns only off or on

Comment: $('input[name=BankAccountTypeGroup]:checked').val()  does work.  This is what I want.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Radio buttons are grouped by the `name` attribute, so your current selector should work fine (without even looping) -- if you have multiple groups of common named groups, you can use the `^=` (starts with) inside attribute selector to get all the groups.

Example, you have multiple radio groups starting with "BankAccount"

```
var groups = $(":radio[name^=BankAccount]:checked").map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

`.map()` returns a nice array of all your checked values for radio groups starting with "BankAccount"

Answer (score 0):

```
var boxes = $('input[name=BankAccountTypeGroup]:checked');
if (boxes.length==1) //test it, maybe there is no radio checked
    {
        alert(boxes[0].value); //boxes[0] is the first and only-checked element, 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
var $boxes = $('#yourcontaineridOfAllCheckboxes').find('input[type=radio]:checked'));
    $($boxes).each(function () {
       if ($(this).val() == 'Savings') {
           //
       }
    })
```

Comment: The OP is looking for radio buttons, not check boxes.

Comment: OP can just put radio instead of checkbox.